# Robot Framework SyntaxError: mismatched input ':' expecting EOF

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I'm writing a test suite with RF with Selenium for Java, using Hi-Fi's SeleniumLibrary.

I'm implementing some high-level keywords using variables kept in a Variables.robot file like this:

```
*** Variables ***
${EXPECTED URL}                       https://www.test.com
```

And this file is being imported in my Resource.robot, to be used in keywords, like this:

```
*** Keywords ***

Main Links Are Working
  Wait Until Element Is Visible       ${SIGN UP IMG}
  ${link}                             Get Element Attribute  ${SIGN UP IMG}@href
  Should Be True                      ${link}==${EXPECTED URL}/signup/new
```

This is what I get when executing:

```
Evaluating expression 'https://www.test.com/signup/new==https://www.test.com/signup/new' failed: SyntaxError: mismatched input ':' expecting EOF (<string>, line 1)
```

(I had to replace the actual company url for a dummy url in my examples but I tried to keep a similar url structure)

I'm not sure what's going on. As far as I can see, it's comparing two exactly matching URLs, but somehow it's not recognizing the ':' character. I tried escaping it with a backslash (:) but the same error shows up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expressions need to be valid python expressions after all of the variables have been substituted. You either need to add quotes, or use the special `$variable` syntax (see [Evaluating Expressions](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluating%20expressions) in the BuiltIn library documentation):

```
Should Be True  '${link}'=='${EXPECTED URL}/signup/new'
```

-or-

```
Should Be True  $link == $expected_url
```

Comment: Ohh, so adding quotes make these literal strings that can be compared, right?